# Keeping alive laravel echo server with supervisor or pm2

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, supervisord, pm2

I tried to keep alive laravel echo server with `supervisor` or `pm2` with these `confs`:

Supervisor:

```
[program:laravel-echo-server]
command=/var/www/html/backend-api laravel-echo-server start
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=apache
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/laravel-echo-server.log
```

Where in log I get:

```
Could not open input file: /var/www/html/backend-api/laravel-echo-server
```

And for `pm2`:

I made `echo.json` file with:

```
{
  "name": "echo",
  "script": "laravel-echo-server",
  "args": "start"
}
```

Started by `pm2 start echo.json`

I did same in supervisor for laravel queues and they work.
Also I can manually start laravel-echo-server..
I've seen that some supervisor examples navigate to `/bin/laravel-echo-server start` as command and as `directory = /to/dir` but I don't have laravel-echo-server within bin..

Comment: You need to execute `laravel-echo-server start` inside `/var/www/html/backend-api/` so you can add `directory=/var/www/html/backend-api`  and change the command to `command=laravel-echo-server start`

Comment: @RolandStarke does not work and I get no logs....

Comment: Mm but if you get no error could it be that it works?

Comment: On client side for listening I still get network error, that error goes away when laravel echo server is started

Comment: By running supervisorctl I get FATAL: 'laravel-echo-server' command cannot be found

Comment: Mm looks like the laravel-echo-server is not inside your $PATH or at least not that of supervisor. Could you run `which laravel-echo-server`? (it should give you a path) And then you can write the full path like `command=/path/to/laravel-echo-server start`

Comment: @RolandStarke I did as u said and path is wtf /root/..../Node.x.x.x./laravel-echo-server..... Not I get this error:

`2019-09-13 11:13:24,180 INFO gave up: laravel-echo entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly`

Comment: Mm and the lines before that error? Sry I don't know further. (I would maybe try to find out if its a problem with the rights (`user=apache`) or if somehow the laravel-echo-server can not find the `laravel-echo-server.json` file.)

Comment: @RolandStarke before that I just get  `exited: laravel-echo (exit status 127; not expected)` I added startretries=3 and 3 times it spawn laravel-echo-server on and exit with 127 status and then on the end this fatal state

Comment: @RolandStarke well laravel-echo-server start works manually from directory... and I use user=apache for laravel queue:work as well and it works

Comment: Could you add `redirect_stderr=true` to your supervisor config and then look inside `/var/log/supervisor/laravel-echo-server.log` (the laravel queue is inside /var/www/ so it makes sense it works with the apache user, but the laravel-echo-server is located elsewhere, so the apache user probably has no rights to execute a file located in /root/...)

Comment: That probably is it I will change to root, but is root good to use or should I create user with permission for only this execution and use that?

I get error: supervisor: couldn't exec /root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/bin/laravel-echo-server: EACCES
So it may be that apache cant execute it

Comment: Yes that was it! If you are not bored get all together from this comments and add it as answer. Just in case someone else get stucked

Comment: Sadly I don't know if you should run it with root. (Personalty I just did it with root as well, here is  the setup I used for a laravel project: https://gist.github.com/rolandstarke/51f1eedad6e7ed5d355a0c3123e5d127#file-supervisor-ini)

Answer (score 2):

first install laravel-echo-server globally with this command:

```
npm install -g laravel-echo-server
```

then create your laravel echo configs with command (laravel-echo-server init) and make sure that your config file putted into project folder and config file must named "laravel-echo-server.json"

after that install supervisor and write your supervisor file like this:

```
[program:laravel-echo-server]
command=laravel-echo-server start --dir="/var/www/html/backend-api"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=apache
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/laravel-echo-server.log
```

then start your supervisor with running these commands :

```
sudo supervisorctl reread

sudo supervisorctl update

sudo supervisorctl start laravel-echo-server
```

this way i already used in several projects

Comment: Thanks but if u saw comments, we figured out whats problem

Answer (score 0):

So here I think you need to create a separate file for running laravel-echo-server continuously with help of PM2.

For that, you need to create a file with `anyname.config.js` and add this code inside this file

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'laravel-echo-server',
            script: 'laravel-echo-server',
            instances: 1,  // default 'laravel-echo-server' required 1 instance only to work
            exec_mode: 'fork',  // default
            interpreter: 'node', // default
            args: 'start',
            error_file: './storage/logs/pm2/pm2.error.log',
            out_file: './storage/logs/pm2/pm2.out.log',
            pid_file: './storage/logs/pm2/pm2.pid.log',
            cwd: "PROJECT_ROOT_DIRECTORY_PATH",  // var/www/html/project
        }
    ]
};
```

After that you need to set following code in `laravel-echo-server.json` file on root level of project directory.

```
{
    "authHost": "http://example.com",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

That's it. Now you can start your node laravel-echo-server by watch anyname.config.js file with PM2.

To start PM2 Watch list and run the server use `sudo pm2 start anyname.config.js --watch`