# Laravel broadcasting : laravel-echo-server / redis stop handling event irregularly after 3-4 hours or once in a day

Tags: php, laravel, redis, socket.io, broadcasting

I've implemented broadcasting functionality using driver redis and laravel-echo-server.

Everything is working fine events are working fine too, but the problem is, after some span of time, 3 hours or 6 hours (time is not fixed) , it disconnects automatically even laravel-echo-server is running in the background.

But if I refresh the page everything starts working fine again. I've tries many ways but I could not figure out what is the problem.

My project will run on localhost forever.

File .env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
LARAVEL_ECHO_PORT=6001
```

laravel-echo-server.js

```
{
     "authHost": "http://localhost",
     "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
     "clients": [],
     "database": "redis",
     "databaseConfig": {
         "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
        "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
     },
     "devMode": false,
     "host": null,
     "port": "6001",
     "protocol": "http",
     "socketio": {},
     "secureOptions": 67108864,
     "sslCertPath": "",
     "sslKeyPath": "",
     "sslCertChainPath": "",
     "sslPassphrase": "",
     "subscribers": {
    "http": true,
    "redis": true
     },
     "apiOriginAllow": {
    "allowCors": false,
    "allowOrigin": "",
    "allowMethods": "",
    "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

laravel-echo-setup.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ":" + window.laravel_echo_port,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    disableStats: true,
    forceTLS: false,
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] 
});
```

Comment: Can this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922146/keeping-alive-laravel-echo-server-with-supervisor-or-pm2) help

Comment: Actually , laravel-echo-server is fine that is not stopping . Problem is in the web page socket.io disconnects automatically after some span of time like 4 , 5 or 6 hours.  And if i refresh browser window it start working fine .

Comment: I know that this is a poor solution. You can refresh page with JS on every hour or if you can do it in callback on socket failure, until you find a better solution

Comment: I'm already handling an socket disconnect event but you know it is not disconnecting  from echo server it just stops handle the events

Comment: It is browser who leave the connection irregularly and when we refresh it , again all things going fine .

Comment: Ok , so finally got the solution : in laravel-echo-server.js append these two lines "pingInterval": 25000,
"pingTimeout": 60000"

And below lines in laravel-echo-setup.js
reconnect: true,
reconnectionAttempts: 12, 
reconnectionDelay: 5000